# How can I use deeplearning4j Word2vec with Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, word2vec, deeplearning4j, dl4j

When using spark-submit, I need to send the dependencies with --packages. Which package should I use?

I tried making an uber jar which contain the dependencies, but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please specify an existing file
```

The error is the result of the following code:

```
String path = "hdfs:///user/data.txt";
SentenceIterator iter = new LineSentenceIterator(new File(path));
```

Answer (score 2):

Deeplearning4j actually has its own spark version of word2vec.
Check in our examples here:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j-scaleout/spark/dl4j-spark-nlp/src/test/java/org/deeplearning4j/spark/models/embeddings/word2vec/Word2VecTest.java#L57

Comment: The link is dead.  Try this instead:  https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/57befb80aeb53523413c363a4edb15d682d59836/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/word2vec/Word2VecRawTextExample.java